# How to color bar chart & rotate axis label in echarts4r

Tags: r, echarts4r

I have basic df and I'm trying to add different color for each bar. According to e_color doc we need to provide a vector of colors but it doesn't work, I'm getting only one color from the vector. Additionally I'd like to rotate by 45dg x axis label but haven't found any solution yet. Any help with both topics much appreciated.

Thanks
Adam

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = c('AAA','BBB','CCC','DDD','EEE','FFF','GGG'),
  y = c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70)
  )

my_colors <- brewer.pal(7, "GnBu")

df %>% e_chart(x) %>% e_bar(y) %>% e_color(my_colors) %>% e_x_axis(label = list(rotate = 45))
```

Comment: I've not heard of e_chart.  `ggplot2` should have everything you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to assign your colors to your data frame named `color`. Then you can add them by using `e_add` with `"itemStyle"`. To rotate your labels you should use `axisLabel` like this:

```
library(echarts4r)
library(RColorBrewer)
my_colors <- brewer.pal(7, "GnBu")

df$color <- my_colors

df %>% 
  e_chart(x) %>% 
  e_bar(y) %>% 
  e_add("itemStyle", color) %>%
  e_x_axis(axisLabel = list(rotate = 45))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there any documentation you have for both? I could not find it

Comment: @awoj, No problem! Check this post https://echarts4r.john-coene.com/articles/advanced.html and this https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/echarts4r/versions/0.1.1/topics/e_axis